# Adding video card and Ubuntu stuck on boot

Tags: drivers, ati, video

I am working on Ubuntu 13.04 and I have 
Radeon 7950 video card working good with 
the latest AMD driver.

The problem occurs when I am adding 
another exactly the same video card 
now the boot stuck, and even if 
I am trying to halt it with Ctrl + Alt + F1 
it halt anyway.

I'll appreciate any help on that one.

Thanks in advance
Roman

Answer (score 0):

just re-read your post
--you are trying to add a second video card, or swap it out?

If this is a second card it's possible you might also be creating an IRQ resource
   conflict on your motherboard - check your bios to verify.

You also should try changing the boot options in grub

If you don't normally see grub at bootup, hold the shift key during boot.

Once at the grub2 menu select a kernel you want to boot, and press e.

Between all the gibberish will be a huge line beginning with "linux /boot/vmlinuz-". Put the cursor at the beginning of that line and press the End key to get at the end of it (it probably ends with "quiet splash").

Edit and/or following parameters: nomodeset noacpi noapm pci=noacpi acpi=off apm=off

Press Ctrl-x to boot.

- Once logged in, you can edit grub permanently.  Press ALT-F2

  gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
- There should be a line:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
- add your parameters there (between the quotes). Save, and exit the editor. Then run:

Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If the above doesn't help you can also try starting with recovery mode:

Once at the grub menu choose "recovery mode" if available, or go to "Ubuntu Advanced Options" and then choose recovery mode.  Hopefully in this mode you'll see the errors causing the problem.

Comment: I am trying to add second card. What's about BIOS how I can identify any conflict there , I don't see any error or warning just Ubuntu stuck on that line.

Comment: Every bios is different as well as the way to acess it.  It might be delete key, escape key, F2, F8, F10, F11, for F12.  Usually resource allocation is under an "Advanced Settings" category, and often the bios will point out the conflict once you are there.  However without having the same BIOS as you I'll be of little help.  However, I believe trying to boot into recovery mode might provide some errors to help solidify this as the problem, or shed more light onto the real culprit.